# Comparing two comma separated text files

Tags: powershell, text

I've got 2 text files, one with a list of registry settings from a remote server, and one with the preferred registry settings.  The files are formatted the same, ie:

ServValues.txt

```
HKLM:\software\Wow6432Node\Policies\Citrix\, Evidence, DesktopKind, Private
HKLM:\software\Wow6432Node\Policies\Citrix\, MultimediaPolicies, EnableRAVE, 1
HKLM:\software\Wow6432Node\Policies\Citrix\, ICAPolicies, ACRLogEvents, 1
HKLM:\software\Wow6432Node\Policies\Citrix\, ICAPolicies, ACRRequireAuth, 0
```

CorrectValues.txt

```
HKLM:\software\Wow6432Node\Policies\Citrix\, Evidence, DesktopKind, Private
HKLM:\software\Wow6432Node\Policies\Citrix\, MultimediaPolicies, EnableRAVE, 1
HKLM:\software\Wow6432Node\Policies\Citrix\, ICAPolicies, ACRLogEvents, 0
HKLM:\software\Wow6432Node\Policies\Citrix\, ICAPolicies, ACRRequireAuth, 2
```

I'm trying to write a powershel script to compare these two files, and, on finding a discrepancy (like on the third and fourth lines) create a new log file like:

Discrepancies.txt

> RemoteSever >HKLM:\software\Wow6432Node\Policies\Citrix\, ICAPolicies, ACRLogEvents set to 1, should be 0
>
> RemoteServer >>HKLM:\software\Wow6432Node\Policies\Citrix\, ICAPolicies, ACRRequireAuth set to 0, should be 2

I'm only comparing the values after the last comma in any line, the rest are assumed to be the same.
I'm stumped, any tips?

Comment: I mean, clearly the first step, I would think, is something like:
`$ServerSettings = get-file ServValues.txt`
`$CorrectSettings = get-file CorrectValues.txt`

What's hard for me after that is parsing through two arrays like that at the same time, comparing values across each.

Comment: Have you try starting use `compare-object` ??

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Compare-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156812.aspx)?

If that won't work, you'll have to use a standard `for` loop:

```
filter Split-RegSettingLine
{
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        $Line
    )
    if( $Line -notmatch '^(.*), ([^,]+)$' )
    {
        Write-Error ('Invalid line: {0}' -f $Line)
        return
    }
    $matches[1],$matches[2]
}

$ServerSettings = Get-Content ServValues.txt
$CorrectSettings = Get-Content CorrectValues.txt

if( $ServerSettings.Length -ne $CorrectSettings.Length )
{
    Write-Warning ('Files have different number of lines.  WATCH OUT!')
}

for( $idx = 0 $idx -lt $ServerSettings.Length -and $idx -lt $CorrectSettings.Length; ++$idx )
{
    $serverKey,$serverValue = $ServerSettings[$idx] | Split-RegSettingLine
    $correctKey,$correctValue = $CorrectSettings[$idx] | Split-RegSettingLine

    if( $serverKey -ne $correctKey )
    {
        Write-Error ('Line {0}: mismatched keys: <{1}> <=> <{2}>' -f $idx,$serverKey,$correctKey)
        continue
    }

    if( $serverValue -ne $correctValue )
    {
        Write-Error ('Line {0}: key {1}: set to <{2}>, should be <{3}>' -f $idx,$serverKey,$serverValue,$correctValue
    }
}
```